# What is the minimum and the maximum perimeter of a triangle with area $x$ that can be inscribed in a circle?

Tags: calculus, geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, maxima-minima

[Posted in MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/459543/what-is-the-minimum-and-the-maximum-perimeter-of-a-triangle-with-area-x-that-c) since it has been open in MSE for over 2 months.

The area of the largest triangle that can be inscribed in a circle of raidus $1$ is $\displaystyle \frac{3 \sqrt{3}}{4}$ for a equilateral triangle and it also gives the perimeter is $3\sqrt{3}$. For any $\displaystyle 0 \le x \le \frac{3 \sqrt{3}}{4}$ we can ask the minimum perimeter $f(x) $and maximum perimeter $g(x)$ of triangles with area $x$ inscribed in a circle of radius $1$. I ran a simulation to calculate the values of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ for all $x$ in this interval and obtained the plot below.

[image]

For the maximum perimeter, trivially $g(0) = 4$ and $\displaystyle g\left(\frac{3 \sqrt{3}}{4}\right) = 3 \sqrt{3}$. The graph of $g(x)$ appears to be a straight line as shown by the blue line. Fitting a straight line through these two points gives the model

$$
g(x) = 4 + \left(4 - \frac{16}{3\sqrt{3}}\right)x \tag 1
$$

Can this be proven? For the minimum perimeter we have trivially $f(0) = 0$ and $\displaystyle f\left(\frac{3 \sqrt{3}}{4}\right) = 3 \sqrt{3}$ and $f(1) = 2+2\sqrt{2}$ corresponding to an isosceles right triangle. Fitting a curve with the data for $g(x)$ suggests a model of the form $f(x) = (2+\sqrt{2})x^a$ with $a \approx 0.306$ however this model with inconsistent with the fact that $\displaystyle f\left(\frac{3 \sqrt{3}}{4}\right) = 3 \sqrt{3}$ hence this model was discarded.

**Question**: What is the minimum and the maximum perimeter of a triangle with area $x$ and circumradius $1$?

Comment: I've managed to prove the triangle must be isosceles for a maximum or minimum perimeter (see below). I used Lagrange multipliers but strongly suspect there's a more intuitive, geometric approach. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

We can show that the maximum and minimum perimeters occur precisely when the triangle is isosceles.

Say the centre of the circle is $O$, and the triangle's vertices are $A$, $B$, and $C$.

Let $\theta_A=\frac12 \angle BOC$, $\theta_B=\frac12 \angle COA$ and $\theta_C=\frac12 \angle AOB$.

The area of the triangle is
$$\Delta=\frac12 \left(\sin 2\theta_A+\sin 2\theta_B+\sin 2\theta_C\right)$$

and its perimeter is
$$p=2 \left(\sin\theta_A+\sin\theta_B+\sin\theta_C\right)$$

Also, $\theta_A+\theta_B+\theta_C=\pi$, and each angle lies in the interval $(0,\pi)$.

We wish to find extreme values of $p$ given a fixed $\Delta$; we can use Lagrange multipliers for this. Define
$$F \left(\theta_A,\theta_B,\theta_C,\mu,\nu \right)=2 \left(\sin\theta_A+\sin\theta_B+\sin\theta_C\right) + \mu \left(\sin 2\theta_A+\sin 2\theta_B+\sin 2\theta_C - 2\Delta \right) + \nu\left(\theta_A+\theta_B+\theta_C - \pi \right)$$

The partial derivative wrt $\theta_A$ is
$$F_{\theta_A}=2\cos\theta_A+2\mu \cos 2\theta_A + \nu$$

Setting this and the other partial derivatives to zero gives a set of five equations to solve:
$$\begin{align} 2\cos\theta_A+2\mu \cos 2\theta_A + \nu &=0 \\
2\cos\theta_B+2\mu \cos 2\theta_B + \nu &=0 \\
2\cos\theta_C+2\mu \cos 2\theta_C + \nu &=0 \\
\sin 2\theta_A+\sin 2\theta_B+\sin 2\theta_C &= 2\Delta \\
\theta_A+\theta_B+\theta_C &=\pi \end{align}$$

We'll prove that these equations imply two of the angles are the same.

For a contradiction, let's assume that they are in fact pairwise distinct. From the first two equations, we have
$$\cos\theta_A+\mu \cos 2\theta_A = \cos\theta_B+\mu \cos 2\theta_B$$

so that
$$\mu = \frac{\cos\theta_B- \cos \theta_A}{\cos2\theta_A-\cos 2\theta_B}=\frac{-1}{2(\cos \theta_A+\cos \theta_B)}$$

(note that, since $\theta_C \neq 0$, $\cos \theta_A + \cos \theta_B \neq 0$.) Likewise,
$$\mu = \frac{\cos\theta_C - \cos \theta_B}{\cos2\theta_B-\cos 2\theta_C}=\frac{-1}{2(\cos \theta_B+\cos \theta_C)}$$

so that
$$\cos \theta_A+\cos \theta_B = \cos \theta_B+\cos \theta_C$$

ie $\cos \theta_A = \cos \theta_C$

We assumed that $A\neq C$; so this means $\theta_A=-\theta_C$; but this contradicts the fact that the angles lie in $(0,\pi)$.

This contradiction proves that two of the angles must be the same - ie $ABC$ is isosceles.

Comment: I realise this doesn't fully answer the question, but you can use the fact the triangle is isosceles to get a quartic for $\sin\theta_A$ and solve from there.